# Why does my program compile but not do anything?

Tags: c, function, variables, declaration, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int * get_digs(long card, int digs, int idigs[]);

int main()
{
    long card = get_long("Number: ");
    int digs = ceil(log10(card));
    int idigs[digs];

    get_digs(card, digs, &idigs[digs]);

    for(int k = 0; k == digs; k++) // This loop is to check if the program is doing what I'm 
    {                              // asking it to do.
        printf("%i", idigs[k]);
    }
}

int * get_digs(long cd, int dg, int idg[])
{
    int j = dg;
    int dig = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i == dg; i++)
    {
        dig = floor(cd / pow(10, j));
        j--;
        idg[i] = dig % 10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program is supposed to take an input from the user, let's say a credit card, get its digits and store them on an array. The program compiles, but it doesn't even print the `for` loop on the main function... It just asks for input.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for(int k = 0; k == digs; k++)` would at most iterate a single time, if `digs` is 0 (which I assume it isn't)

Comment: in your `get_digs(card, digs, &idigs[digs]);` function call `idigs` is an array with indexes `0` to just before `digs` (`idigs[0]`, `idigs[1]`, ..., `idigs[digs - 1]`). The element `idigs[digs]` does not exist, passing its address to the function looks wrong (though it's legal).

Comment: get_long() is missingin your example.

Comment: In theory, digs is equal to the lenght of the user's input. So yeah, it should at least iterate one time. I'm confused

Comment: The very first thing the program does is call `get_long("Number: ")`, which I guess is what you mean by "it just asks for input" (which is doing something).  So are you saying that *after* you enter a number and press [enter], the program terminates without producing any further output?

Comment: Exactly, John.  The program does call get_long, but after I press [enter], nothing happens. @JohnBollinger

Comment: There is a difference between what @UnholySheep said, **at most**, and what you said, **at least**. A `for` loop only runs as long as the middle conditional is true. Your condition `k == digs` is pretty much always false. It should be `k < digs`.

Comment: Oh. I actually messed up the condition on all the for loops I wrote. Thanks, @kaylum

Comment: It needs to be`<` not `<=`. Otherwise you'll get a buffer overflow because valid array indices are from `0` to `digs-1`

Comment: You edited your own question, fixing the bugs as proposed in the answers. That makes the question useless for others to read. Please note that SO is not an online proofing service.

Comment: I rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second expression in a `for` loop's control block is a condition for iterating, not for breaking from the loop.  Thus, this `for` loop ...

> ```
>     for(int k = 0; k == digs; k++)
> ```

... executes the loop body only if `k` is equal to `digs`, and that will be true the first time the condition is checked only if `digs` is zero, which you (reasonably) do not expect to be the case.  Furthermore, unless `k` were also modified inside the loop body, which it isn't in your code, the body would never execute more than once.  It's similar in effect, then, to `if (k == digs)`, and of course the loop body is not executed even once.

The standard idiom for what you are trying to do uses a `<` expression in the condition:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < digs; k++)
```